# ApolloClient: How to synchronize Apollo cache after update on the server?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-apollo, apollo-client

I am trying to synchronize apollo cache after update on the server.
Should I write to the cache directly or can I refetch only updated data ?

I am actually trying to refetch only updated data, but still not working yet.

I have a `programs(title: String)` query that fetch all programs if title is empty, see code below:

```
class Programs extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const FIND_PROGRAMS = gql`query findPrograms($title: String) {
      programs(title: $title) {  id title description }
    }`

    return (
      // The query fetch all programs if title is empty
      <Query query={FIND_PROGRAMS} variables={{ title: '' }}> 
        {({ data, error, loading, refetch }) => {
          if (loading) return <span>Loading</span>
          if (error) return <span>{error.message}</span>

          return (
            <div>
              { data.programs.map(program => <ProgramSummary program={program} />)}

              <button
                onClick={() => axios
                  .patch('path/to/endpoint', payload)
                  .then(updatedProgram => {
                    // Should I update the cache myself with something like this ?
                    // client.writeData(...) 

                    // Or should I refetch only updated Program like this ?
                    refetch({ title: updatedProgram.title }) // Not working yet
                  })
                }
              >
                UpdateProgram
              </button>
            </div>
          )
        }}
      </Query>
    )
  }
}
```

My refetch is not working, I should be doing something wrong.
Please help.

Comment: It works with `refetch()` without variables;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think non-functioning behavior is due to the fact that you are trying to update an specific object (updated data) passing GraphQL an array of objects (which is what your query returns and therefore your refresh). I mean, you don't ask someone to update something and then give them a bunch of stuff, you just give that specific item you want to get updated.

I'd suggest using a mutation to make the update instead, with it you'll get your data automatically refreshed as the docs said, which is more or less what I said before.

"[...] If you're updating a single item, you usually don't need an update function as long as you return the item's id and the property you updated [...]".

See https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/mutations#update.

Hope I helped you.

Comment: I am doing my update outside of GraphQL, with simple REST endpoint, the update could have occured from another user. Let me ask differently. The refetch function seems to accept some variables which CAN differ from those of the orignal query. So it should be possible to refetch a different set of data,  based on the new variable values. Here I am just trying to refetch a single item from the initial result. I think it am still in the API specs, but why is it not working ?

Comment: access to your project would be of great help :)